# How to change the field label in an API response

Tags: views, 8

How to change `field_canonicalurl` to `canonicalUrl` and `field_teaser` to `Teaser`?

Below is my API output from my View:

```
[{"field_canonicalurl":"","title":"This is the title ","field_teaser":"\u003Cp\u003EIn this is the teaser \n" }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to field settings of the Rest export view, add Alias for each field, Save. 
That's it. You're done

[image]